# how to make pythonic Nested List

Tags: python

I'd like to make nested list

```
given_list = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]] # each element : range(0, n), num of element : m
new_list = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], ..., [2, 2, 2]] # total num : n^m
```

How do I make it?

I tried to overlap the for statement m times, but I don't think it's pythonic.

Comment: what is the significance of `given_list` ? what if it had only 2 members. will output change ?

Comment: if it had 2 members, the output is [[0 ,0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], ..., [2,2]].
Each element of the input is the same.

Comment: no I mean  `[ [0,1,2] , [0,1,2] ]`

Comment: I also mean that, each element is range(0, 3) and num of element : 2, so output's total num is 3^2 = 9

Comment: If you are trying to compute a cross product, the output will have far more than 9 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to compute the product of the lists in `given_list`:

```
> from itertools import product
> list(product(*given_list))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

If you really need a list of lists, rather than a list of tuples, you'll have to call `list` on each element.

```
[list(t) for t in product(*given_list)]
```